# Received RunTimeError when using LoadOperation

Tags: silverlight, runtime-error, domainservices

I have receive an Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger Error
An Unhandled Exception("Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application
Code: 4004
Category: MangedRuntimeError
Message: System.ServiceMode.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException:

once i loaded a line of code as

```
Public Sub New()
InitializeComponent()
Dim context As New OrganizationContext()
context.Load(context.GetTimeTablesQuery(), AddressOf LoadMonday, Nothing)

End Sub

Private Sub LoadMonday(ByVal obj As LoadOperation(Of TimeTable))

Dim btnMonday(20) As Button
For a As Integer = 0 To 19
            btnMonday(a) = New Button()
            btnMonday(a).Height = 23
            btnMonday(a).Width = 107
            btnMonday(a).Content = timeslot(a)
            btnMonday(a).Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta)

            ' Sets dependency properties
            btnMonday(a).SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1)
            btnMonday(a).SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, a + 1)
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnMonday(a))
        Next
End Sub
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that your obj has error or not by check it [HasError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.operationbase.haserror%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) property. If LoadOperation HasError is true you can call [MarkErrorAsHandled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.operationbase.markerrorashandled%28v=VS.91%29.aspx)

**Example code:**

```
' if there is an error, mark is as handled.
If (obj.HasError) Then
    obj.MarkErrorAsHandled()
End If
```

Comment: Actually wat is the problem ? 
Although it solved the problem. Can I know why this problem pop out?

Comment: obj.Error property has details of the error. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.operationbase.error(v=VS.91).aspx